# Query XML Linq in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I want to retrieve data from XML(which have also an xsd file) using C#. What can it be wrong with my code: 
My Xml file look likes this.

```
<Model_1 xmlns="http://www.3ds.com/xsd/3DXML" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.3ds.com/xsd/3DXML ./3DXML.xsd">
    <Header>
        <item></item>
        <item1></item1>
        <item2></item2>
    </Header>
    <Product>
        <otheritem></otheritem>
        <otheritem1></otheritem1>
        <otheritem2></otheritem2>
    </Product>
    <Books>
        <otheritem></otheritem>
        <otheritem1></otheritem1>
        <otheritem2></otheritem2>
    </Books>
</Model_1>
```

...c#

```
     XDocument xdoc = Document.Load("document.xml")                                                           var items = from item in xdoc.Descendants("Header")
                            select new
                            {
                                _Item= item.Element("Item").Value,
                                _Item1= item.Element("Item1").Value,
                                _Item2= item.Element("Item2").Value,         
                            };

                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    Item= item._Item;
                    Item1 = item._Item1;
                    Item2 = item.Item2;
                }
 Console.WriteLine("show me :" + Item+ " + " + Item1 + " + " + Item2);
```

How can I extract just items from Header and not Product or Books?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use namespace:

```
var ns = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
var header = xdoc.Root.Element(ns + "Header");
```

Also keep in mind - you have lower case `item` in your xml, not `Item`:

```
Item = (string)header?.Element(ns + "item");
Item1 = (string)header?.Element(ns + "item1");
Item2 = (string)header?.Element(ns + "item2");
```

Comment: @maki copied your xml and parsed it successfully. Make sure you are using same xml as you provided in question

Comment: thank you very much. it works now , it was my fault.